# Convert DBF to JSON

Tags: c++, c, database, json, foxpro

I want to convert a Foxpro 2.6 Dos Data file (DBF - DBase III Format) into JSON file.  Do we have any C/C++ Library to convert DBF to JSON as well as back from JSON to DBF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl module `DBD::XBase` will help you.

On Linux: `sudo apt-get install libdbd-xbase-perl`

On Windows: install [ActivePerl](http://activestate.com/perl), then `ppm install DBD::XBase`

After that, you will have command line utility `dbf_dump` (`dbfdump` on Windows) that can convert DBF file into CSV (you will need to use  `--fs ","` switch to create CSV), and then you can convert CSV into JSON.

However, I would recommend learning how Perl DBI works, and writing code that can read from your DBF like from any other SQL/DBI source. Your Perl code may look like this:

```
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:XBase:/path/to/dbfs")
    or die $DBI::errstr;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable");
$sth->execute();
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    # dump ($row->{field1}, $row->{field2}, ...) into your JSON file.
    # you might want to use JSON::XS module here
    # or, you can insert it into PostgreSQL or MySQL via DBI as well
}
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```